# Flutter FlatButton does hide after changing the tab

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So basically when I'm opening my app the button with the
image is loaded and I can click the button/image to call a method. When I'm going to switch the tab 2 times, the button disappears. If I switch the tab 1 time it's still there.

The exception I'm getting:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════ ...........The following assertion was thrown building Container(bg: BoxDecoration(color:MaterialAccentColor(primary value: Color(0xff448aff)))):................................'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4041 pos 12: '_state._widget ==
>   null': is not true.
>   ......................................................User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
>     Scaffold file:///D:/Code%20Projects/instant_catering/lib/main.dart:48:12

The widget that causes the error:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          key: _bottomNavigationKey,
          index: 0,
          height: 50.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.center_focus_weak, size: 45),
            Icon(Icons.content_paste, size: 45),
            Icon(Icons.credit_card, size: 45),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (int tappedIndex) {
            setState(() {
              showScan = pageChooser(tappedIndex);
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: showScan,
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

I already tied to help the state in a variable but that does not seem to work.

Comment: i've fixed it myself by changing the '_MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();' to '_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();'